# JOptionPane action on cancel button

Tags: java, string, swing, comparison, joptionpane

The code I'm trying to compile:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Comienzo
{

    public static void main()
    {
        String nombrepersonaje = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce el nombre de tu personaje");

        if (JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
            Principal.main(new String[] {});
        else
            //do other stuff

        if (nombrepersonaje.equals(""))
            Comienzo.main();
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Bienvenido... " + nombrepersonaje + "!");
    }
}
```

This class and method is called from another class (thing I learnt in this website), now I'd like to ask why Eclipse is telling me I'm comparing identical expressions, what I'm trying to do is: if I press cancel button, go back to `Principal#main` class, I've tried too with

```
if (JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
{
    Comienzo.main();
}
```

But what I'm getting even if I type things in the InputDialog is looping the program, seems that after else whatever I'm writing is "dead code" which I don't understand why.

I'm trying even to remove the brackets after `else` and put

```
else if {nombrepersonaje.equals("")) 
    Comienzo.main();
else 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Bienvenido... " + nombrepersonaje + "!");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It might doesn't have nothing to do, but why do you have an else statement in the main function, if you are not using it?

Comment: Also, you *should not* call other classes `main` method. This is a bad design. Since you're in learning phase, I can only tell you that it works but you're learning this the wrong way.

Comment: @usar: Oh you're right, I should've written else if, I thought that written that way it'd be correct too.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Thanks for the tip, I think I should stop trying to do some big program for myself and finish the books about Java I've started. Just wanted to use the examples of the book I'm reading to do something practical, but you're right, I should learn more things before diving into this kind of troubles, hehe. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare the returned value of the method `showInputDialog`, which in this case is a `String`, with `null` (the `showInputDialog` returns `null`, if you click the `Cancel` button):

```
public class Class
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Are you serious?");

        if(result == null)
            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEFINETELY SERIOUS!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is something like this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Comienzo {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a value");

        if (inputValue == null) {
            System.out.println("CANCEL");
        } else if (inputValue.equals("")) {
            Comienzo.main(args);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Bienvenido... " + inputValue + "!");
        }
    }
}
```

What you did by JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION was comparing two constants with each other that happen to have the same value. As the constants cannot change according to your input, your code cannot react on the input.

Comment: Btw. As Luiggi Mendoza pointed out, calling the main method recursively is not very pretty - it would be better to implement a loop.